# toggle visibility of a layer (the state property) in Acrobat not working

Tags: javascript, scope, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm trying to toggle layer visibility in an **Acrobat pdf** by setting the `state` property to either `true` or `false`.  It works fine in a proof of concept pdf, but it's not working here.  I feel like this is a scope issue, because I'm getting into the switch statement but the states aren't toggling. I feel like I'm not referencing `STARS` in `displayRating` correctly with respect to the document.  Any ideas? It seems like the result of the splice suddenly isn't the same as what that item is in the `LAYERS` array once it's pushed into `STARS`. Thanks!

```
// document javascript    
var STARS = [];
function init(){
    var LAYERS = this.getOCGs();
    var l = LAYERS.length;   
    for(var i = 0;i<l;i++){
        if(/^(STAR_)/i.test(LAYERS[i].name)==true){
            STARS.push(LAYERS.splice(i,1,null));
        };
    }
}
function displayRating(r){
    // called from a button in the pdf
    switch(parseInt(r)){
        case 3:
            STARS[0].state = STARS[1].state = STARS[2].state = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            STARS[0].state = STARS[1].state = true;
            STARS[2].state = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            STARS[0].state = true;
            STARS[1].state = STARS[2].state = false;
            break;
        default:
            STARS[0].state = STARS[1].state = STARS[2].state = false;
    }
}
init();
```

**Note:** In the Acrobat SDK pdf, the `state` property is described on page 520.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: It turns out the `splice` statement was causing the problems.  It was recording the null value into the LAYERS array and then pushing `null` into the STARS array.  I thought it would return the value from the `splice` first, and then fill it with `null` after, but that wasn't the case.  Solution was to just push the matched value without the splice.